# QuickTime component with Xcode 3.2: C++ compilation errors

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, quicktime

I'm trying to compile the Xiph [QuickTime component](http://xiph.org/quicktime/development.html) Xcode project on OS X. It depends on a number of libraries such as libflac and Theora; all of those dependencies appear to be C code which all compiles nicely with the 10.5 SDK. However, when it comes to compiling the component itself, I get a number of errors, mostly along the lines of

```
src/flac-1.1.0/src/libFLAC/include/protected/file_decoder.h:26:0 src/flac-1.1.0/src/libFLAC/include/protected/file_decoder.h:26: 
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'FLAC__FileDecoderState'
```

and

```
/Users/me/Developer/objc/xiph-qt/build-macosx/../OggImport/src/importer_types.h:99:0 
/Users/me/Developer/objc/xiph-qt/build-macosx/../OggImport/src/importer_types.h:99: 
error: syntax error before 'Track'
```

After searching around on the World Wide Web and SO, it appears that the problem might have to do with C++ and the way structs are defined. I don't see any Objective-C code intermixed in there per se, so I expected the code to just compile, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a build flag or two to bring gcc to its senses.

I've asked the question on one of the Xiph.org mailing lists but it looks like the project hasn't seen much development time in the past year. Would appreciate any pointers as to what to kick and where to get it to whirr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track data type is used in QuickTime framework which does not work in 64 bit architecture. To compile the code you need to use 32-bit Intel architecture in your project settings. You should have no problems with compiling it with 10.5 and 10.6 SDKs.